# Does solvate isomers exist for coordination compounds with ammonia solvent as ligand?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers

I could find many sources confirming the hydrate isomerism(with water as solvent) but I couldn't find any information about any other solvent. In all the sources "hydrate/solvate isomerism" is written but no example with any other solvent.

I came across this question:

> The total number of possible isomers for $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4Cl2]Br2}$ are?

If we consider $\ce{[Pt(NH3)3Cl2Br]Br.NH3}$ and $\ce{[Pt(NH3)3ClBr2]Cl.NH3}$ also, then the answer should be 12. Without them, the answer would be 6.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I have seen [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/100472/102492). But I don't think the reasoning is correct because hydrate isomers do exist.

Comment: I can produce no example nor completely refute their existence. However, they should be significantly rarer than hydrates, because ammonia is both a much better ligand than water and is much more volatile, both factors which should destabilise ammonia solvates.

Comment: Also, [$\ce{Cu[PtCl6]·18NH3}$](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/coordination+compounds)

Comment: Also I would like to ask, does all the 6 ionisation isomers do exist in real, or are they only theoretical?

Comment: Some links: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Experimentally-observed-decomposition-temperatures-Tdec-for-selected-metal-borohydrides_fig4_261564719 ... https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Conditions-for-the-ammonothermal-crystal-growth-of-metal-halide-ammoniates-and-of_tbl2_281290526

Comment: if you consider hydrate isomerism, shouldn't you (well theoretically) consider ammoniated isomers too?

Comment: @napstablook what do you mean by ammoniated isomers? I think it makes sense to consider isomers with NH3 outside the coordination sphere as the OP suggests, are you referring to such isomers as "ammoniated isomers"?

Comment: @BoxBoxBoxBox yes you are thinking right.

Comment: @NilayGhosh but the compound you have mentioned does not have the same molecular formula so it cannot be an isomer.

Comment: I am considering complexes which have ammonia outside of coordination sphere. It's surprising that we have hydrates but rarely do we encounter ammoniates like these. @Ritil