# Total number of Isomers of [Co(NH3)5(NO2)](NO3)2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry, solvents, isomers

I encountered this question in my country's Chemistry textbook of class 12. No solutions are published, but the answer given at the back states - "There are 10 possible isomers. (Hint: There are geometrical, ionisation
and linkage isomers possible)"

I think the answer should be 9 by considering geometrical, ionisation, linkage and solvate isomerism.

Recently a problem came in the JEE Advanced Examination (entrance exam for admissions into the IITs) Paper 1 Chemistry section

[image]

Complex is [Pt(NH3)4Cl2]Br2

What should be the correct answer? Do we consider solvate isomerism with NH3 outside the coordination sphere?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you just have to write down the number, or can you write a few lines with your reasoning?

Comment: You can write down the number with some reasoning and preferably a good source/paper if possible. In the exam we had to just report the answer as an integer

Comment: And if you wrote "9" and they expect "10", you get zero points. Your reasoning will not be taken into account?

Comment: Yes we get 0 points if our answer is not as they expect. They don't ask for any reasoning.

Comment: So they're testing your status of brainwashery, no actual chemistry knowledge. ;-) OK, that's actually sad.

Comment: This is asked recently: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158408/does-solvate-isomers-exist-for-coordination-compounds-with-ammonia-solvent-as-li

Comment: @Karl things are far too worse than you can imagine. people basically worship this exam. there is immense competition. (this is the second toughest exam of the country.) And this exam is the only method to enter into the topmost colleges.

Comment: @Ritil I've read the story from Richard Feynman, when he was teaching on a sabbatical in Brazil in the 50ies, and was very unsettled about the way both the teachers (and books) and most of the students were practising what he thought would never lead to an actual understanding of physics. "Surely you're joking", there are thousands of online copies around on the internet. I think the publishers are happy about the free advertising that keeps a really old and arcane book selling. ;)

Comment: @Karl very few people read Feynman's lecture. The thing is that anyone serious about getting into good college (equivalent to heaven for most materialistic students) won't have any time for it. Definitely not a single teacher can advise or refer to that book. Almost no one is going to value that book unless people change their mindset